# Process Modeling: Connect an Exit block with an Enter block

Tags: anylogic

I have a model with full pallet rack storages with different colors. So I want to transport the pallets from the storage to the pallet rack docks. Is it possible to connect the exit block of the process which fills my storages with an enter block which should transport the pallets to the pallet rack docks? If no, which opportunity I have? 
When I start the process "pallets from storage to dock" with a source block it doesn't work, because it can't take the pallets with my forklifts from the full storage.

[exit_enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1p2a.png)

[storagetodock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvR4m.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily connect any Enter block with any Exit block.

Assume both are in the same agent, just write `myEnterBlock.take(agent)` in the "On Exit" code block of the Exit block.

If they are in different parts of the model, adjust the code to navigate to the enter block (i.e. `main.myEnterBlock.take(agent`).

Check out several example models and read about those blocks in the help to learn more.